# Synchronise Sharepoint 2010 lists with offline windows store app

Tags: sqlite, sharepoint, windows-store-apps, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm currently working on a windows store app which should let the user access to some data stored in Sharepoint 2010 (running on a Windows Server 2008). The users should be able to access these data even if the tablet is offline and cannot access this sharepoint server. To accomplish this, we were considering setting a sqlite database and synchronise it whenever the tablet got access to the sharepoint server.

I was considering building a sync engine within the application but apparently it wasn't that great idea. I'm currently trying to figure out a way to make Microsoft Sync Framework works with Sharepoint's lists but cannot find much information online (maybe i'm looking for the wrong thing?).

Does someone knows a way to allow synchronisation between multiple offline apps and a Sharepoint server ?

The thing which has already been done is a CacheService but I'm guessing that all of it has to be changed to use sqlite offline database...

Thanks for your help :)
dotixx

Comment: I suppose you mean 2007 or 2010?  Would you consider using commercial applications?

Comment: @EricHerlitz That might be an option but if there is a way to do it for free it would be of course better ! :) Do you have any suggestion ? :)

Comment: @EricHerlitz Just noticed i didn't answer to your first question ... It's Sharepoint 2010. Is there any free way to synchronize SP lists and offline windows store app ?

Comment: @doitxx Did you get an answer or solution to this? I'm after the same information.

Comment: @JamesLavery nope sorry ... Apparently MS hasn't thought about this ...